# GLSL pass multiple arguments to shaders

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader

I made a program that displays some textures like this it works just fine:

```cpp
    void Texture::render(int w, int h, uint8_t *buffer)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

        shader.use();
        unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "transform");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
```

And this is the fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    vec4 nColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);  
    FragColor = vec4(nColor.r, nColor.g, nColor.b, 1);
}
```

Normally this works fine, but I need to pass an argument to decide the transparency (currently it's 1 in the `FragColor = vec4(...)`)

I've tried doing this to no avail:

```cpp
void Texture::render(int w, int h, uint8_t *buffer)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

        shader.use();
        unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "transform");
        glUniform1f(transformLoc, 0.5f);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    }
```

And simply changed the fragment shader to this:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform float transparency;

void main()
{
    vec4 nColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);  
    FragColor = vec4(nColor.r, nColor.g, nColor.b, transparency);
}
```

How am I supposed to properly do this? I want to pass transparency as an additional argument.

Comment: You need to use `glGetUniformLocation(..., "transparency")` and `glUniform1f` to pass the value for `transparency` in the shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) (also see [LearnOpenGL - Blending](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending)) and:

```cpp
unsigned int transparencyLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, "transparency");
```

```cpp
float alpha = ...;
glUniform1f(transparencyLoc, alpha);
```

I suggest multiplying the alpha channel of the texture and the value of the uniform in the fragment shader:

```c
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform float transparency;

void main()
{
    vec4 nColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);  
    FragColor = vec4(nColor.rgb, nColor.a * transparency);
}
```

Comment: Oh I should have thought about another location... Thanks! This helped a lot. Using `nColor.rgb` instead of individual ones is a lot more practical as well. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Turgut `.rgb` is called [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling)